# ubercart: finding order id when admin is editing order

Tags: ubercart

I have a custom shipping quote module which adds freight costs to the orders admin comments:

```
$order_id = intval($_SESSION['cart_order']);
uc_order_comment_save($order_id, 0, t($shippingquote_text), 'admin');
```

This works correctly when the user goes through the checkout process.

**Problem:**
How do i find the order id when the admin is manually editing a users order?

For example: admin is on **admin/store/orders/3845/edit** and clicks get shipping quote button - which fires freight quote module

**Want:**
comment is saved to order 3845 w shipping quote details.

My answer below is valid for Ubercart 7.36 as the page doesn't use Ajax.
**UberCart 7.38 Uses Ajax, and the same variable isn't available. Still looking for an answer**

Comment: My answer below is valid for Ubercart 7.36 as it doesnt use Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer after posting the question:  (Valid for Ubercart 7.36)

```
if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
dpm (" do fancy stuff");
dpm($_SESSION['ucga_order_id']);

$order_id = $_SESSION['ucga_order_id'];
 uc_order_comment_save($order_id, 0, t($admin_text), 'admin');

dpm ("end admin fancy");

}
```